# Is the likelihood ratio chi-square always better than the chi-square test when the observed count is more than twice the expected count in any cell?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio

This statement is provided in the [Wikipedia entry for the *G*-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test), though no citation is provided and I have been unable to find support for this statement in any other source.